# Issues with LVM during and after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, lvm

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-34-generic x86_64)
and I keep getting this error. It happened during installation and continues to happen and I have no idea how to fix it and after hours of searching I finally decided to ask.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
duane@Server-Main:/tmp$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lvm2 (2.02.133-1ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'K01lvm' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script lvm2: service lvm already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lvm2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lvm2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```